# Parsing date gives Date of different format to what is specified. (Java)

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I get dates as Strings (ie: 2013-04-07 17:20:16.0) and I need to create Date objects to represent these so that I can set the date's in JSpinners.

I am using this to format the date strings I get:

`DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");`

I am using it like this:

`df.setLenient(false);`

`Date tempDateOld = new Date();`

`tempDateOld = df.parse("2013-04-07 17:20:16.0");`

However this:

`System.out.println(tempDateOld.toString());`

gives this:

`Sun Apr 07 17:20:16 CAT 2013`

Why does it not just give me a Date with the date in the same format? How do I take a date of a given format and create a Date object with the date of the same format.

Any help will save my sanity, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
System.out.println(df.format(tempDateOld));
```

The date by itself does not keep the format.

Comment: As I said, I need to use these Date objects to set the time in Jspinners, your mentioning the fact that the date doesn't keep the format made me look at the Editors for the JSpinners as a possible cause and sure enough there the error was.